# pipenv on Windows 10 does nothing

Tags: python-2.7, pip, pipenv

Whenever I try to run `pipenv` nothing happens. Here are my versions of python and pip:

```
>> python -V
Python 2.7.18
>>pip -V
pip 20.1.1 from c:\program files\python27\lib\site-packages\pip (python 2.7)
```

I have installed `pipenv` successfully:

```
>>pip install pipenv
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: pipenv in c:\users\mjerr\appdata\roaming\python\python27\site-packages (2020.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: enum34; python_version < "3" in c:\program files\python27\lib\site-packages (from pipenv) (1.1.10)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi in c:\program files\python27\lib\site-packages (from pipenv) (2020.6.20)
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in c:\program files\python27\lib\site-packages (from pipenv) (20.0.25)
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv-clone>=0.2.5 in c:\program files\python27\lib\site-packages (from pipenv) (0.5.4)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=36.2.1 in c:\program files\python27\lib\site-packages (from pipenv) (44.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pip>=18.0 in c:\program files\python27\lib\site-packages (from pipenv) (20.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: typing; python_version < "3.5" in c:\program files\python27\lib\site-packages (from pipenv) (3.7.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: filelock<4,>=3.0.0 in c:\program files\python27\lib\site-packages (from virtualenv->pipenv) (3.0.12)
Requirement already satisfied: six<2,>=1.9.0 in c:\program files\python27\lib\site-packages (from virtualenv->pipenv) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: distlib<1,>=0.3.0 in c:\program files\python27\lib\site-packages (from virtualenv->pipenv) (0.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata<2,>=0.12; python_version < "3.8" in c:\program files\python27\lib\site-packages (from virtualenv->pipenv) (1.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-resources>=1.0; python_version < "3.7" in c:\program files\python27\lib\site-packages (from virtualenv->pipenv) (3.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: appdirs<2,>=1.4.3 in c:\program files\python27\lib\site-packages (from virtualenv->pipenv) (1.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: contextlib2; python_version < "3" in c:\program files\python27\lib\site-packages (from importlib-metadata<2,>=0.12; python_version < "3.8"->virtualenv->pipenv) (0.6.0.post1)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in c:\program files\python27\lib\site-packages (from importlib-metadata<2,>=0.12; python_version < "3.8"->virtualenv->pipenv) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: configparser>=3.5; python_version < "3" in c:\program files\python27\lib\site-packages (from importlib-metadata<2,>=0.12; python_version < "3.8"->virtualenv->pipenv) (4.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pathlib2; python_version < "3" in c:\program files\python27\lib\site-packages (from importlib-metadata<2,>=0.12; python_version < "3.8"->virtualenv->pipenv) (2.3.5)
Requirement already satisfied: singledispatch; python_version < "3.4" in c:\program files\python27\lib\site-packages (from importlib-resources>=1.0; python_version < "3.7"->virtualenv->pipenv) (3.4.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: scandir; python_version < "3.5" in c:\program files\python27\lib\site-packages (from pathlib2; python_version < "3"->importlib-metadata<2,>=0.12; python_version < "3.8"->virtualenv->pipenv) (1.10.0)
```

And `pipenv` is found in my PATH and executes, however it doesn't actually do anything other than output a blank line in my console:

```
>>pipenv -V

>>pipenv install

>>pipenv lock --clean

>>
```

I am on Windows 10 Pro Version: 2004, OS build: 19041.329

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It seems the x64 version of python 2.7 doesn't work well on win10.
Try to use x86 of python 2.7